# How to change the scrollbar color in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I've had this problem a long time: I can't see the scrollbar position unless I directly focus on it with my eyes. So it takes a while to scan the location with my eyes if the scrollbar movable object size is really tiny.

How do I customize the color on default Windows XP theme to make it more noticeable for my eyes?

Answer (score 2):

- In the Apperance Tab, Choose Windows XP Style, and choose the color scheme, either Olive green, silver or blue. It will change scrollbar color along with window.
- Add Custom Themes, some of them will change the color of the scroll bars.

**EDIT:**

**1)** Download and install [StyleBuilder](http://www.brothersoft.com/stylebuilder-71534.html). The software is a 30-day trial version.

**2)** Open it. In the left-most side make sure blue is selected (since you don't want to change your theme).

**3)** In the middle of the screen you will see a window, just click on the scroll of the window, the image will be highlighted on the right-most window.

[image]

**4)** Now right click on the image (in the right-most pane) and edit using the 1st option.

[image]

**5)** You will be presented with screen like the following.

[image]

**6)** Paint the first three images, after which your scrollbar should look like this.

[image]

Go to the Files menu and save it. Close the editor.

**7)** Now you will notice that the window in the middle has a black vertical-scrollbar like this.

[image]

**8)** Click on Apply.

[image]

**9)** You will be asked to enter a name for the new style.

[image]

**10)** You are done. This is my "My Computer Window", see the changes. Similarly you can change the color of the horizontal scrollbar.

[image]

Comment: i dont want to mess the theme im using, only want to change one color.

Comment: If Black Color is OK then I can tell you how you can do it.

Comment: ok tell how to make black

Comment: doesnt work on my XP version, it switches the style to win98 style when i apply.

Comment: which version of xp u using is it any hacked version of xp ??

Comment: I tried this one in XP Pro 32 bit (SP3)

Comment: @Neeb if your sound-card is not working it definitely cant be due to this. And for the scrollbar , i think u have done it wrong somewhere, i have changed its color to black many times and it worked for me everytime. I don't know why this is not working for you  @Others please try this method and confirm whether its working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Start, Control Panel, Display, Appearance Tab.

Click the Advanced button.

You're looking for the "3D Objects" item.  However, you won't be able to customize it very much.

Comment: +1 - It will also change the color of the window borders and buttons.

Comment: This only works with the classic scheme.  The XP theme won't work with this except for programs that open without themes (like the command prompt).  Another alternative could be using a high-contrast scheme.

Comment: Yeah TuxRug is right, It doesn't work for the scroll bars :|

Comment: i dont want to mess the theme im using, only want to change one color. Isnt there any program or hack possibility to twiddle those colors somehow? Just ONE color...