# Windows 10 Change Color of Scrollbar

Tags: windows-10, scrollbar

I have visited [Change color of scrollbar in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1112985/change-color-of-scrollbar-in-windows-10) (I couldn't comment there being a new user) and applied the regedits.  I've got both set to 255 0 0.  No change to my scroll bar.  Yes logged out and back in, even restarted, they still ain't red!

Suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It seems there is no build-in way could achieve it in windows 10.Consider using some third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just focusing on my most frequently used programs, for example Chrome, and trying to change it within them.  Used chrome extension Rescroller -

[https://www.techjunkie.com/customize-chrome-scrollbar/#:~:text=A%20little%20further%20down%20the,new%20colors%20for%20those%20buttons](https://www.techjunkie.com/customize-chrome-scrollbar/#:%7E:text=A%20little%20further%20down%20the,new%20colors%20for%20those%20buttons).